# how to represent a big graph in adjacency matrix using vector<>

Tags: matrix, vector, graph, stl

Nodes and edges need to be numbers and weight does not require.
   `typedef long long ll;`
    `vector<ll >v`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

1. `vector<vector<int> > graph;`
2. `vector<int> graph[size];`

Both of the above will create adjacency list. Something like this:-

Let's say input says there is a vertex between `0` and `1` and `2`.

```
[0] -> [1,2]
[1] -> [0,2]
[2] -> [0,1]
```

Now let's say we need to consider `weight` as well, then:-

1. `vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > graph;`
2. `vector<pair<int, int> > graph[size];`

Now in your case just replace `int` with constant that you defined for `long long`

Hope this helps!